# Host monitoring from a docker container

Tags: docker

While I believe the answer is no, I feel I should still ask: is it possible to monitor a host system from within a Docker container?  To make deployments and upgrades easier, I was hoping I could put some monitoring tools inside a container.  Specifically, I'm thinking tools like atop, sar, etc.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Docker philosophy of isolation can be circumvented by mounting host directories into the container (as Datadog client does, for example) or running a container in "[privileged](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration)" container mode. This prevents pid/network/ipc/disk/uts namespacing, allowing access to all devices and effectively launching the process as if it were on the host.

These tools are invaluable when running on an immutable host system such as CoreOS.

But priviledged mode is not necessary if you only want access to certain parts of the host machine. For example Datadog currently launches its [agent](https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent) ("monitoring container") with these flags (specific to its monitoring requirements):

```
docker run -d --name dd-agent -h `hostname` \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /proc/:/host/proc/:ro \
  -v /sys/fs/cgroup/:/host/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -e API_KEY={your_api_key_here} \
  datadog/docker-dd-agent
```

(notice the volume mounts giving read-only access to the hosts `proc` and `cgroup` directories, as well as the docker socket [to monitor the daemon])

Sysdig Cloud requires privileged mode, because it has far deeper system introspection capabilities, whilst also mounting device, process, boot, modules and user directories:

```
docker run --name sysdig-agent --privileged --net host --pid host \
  -e ACCESS_KEY=[ACCESS_KEY] -e TAGS=[TAGS] \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock -v /dev:/host/dev \
  -v /proc:/host/proc:ro -v /boot:/host/boot:ro \
  -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro -v /usr:/host/usr:ro sysdig/agent
```

It is also possible to [add and revoke individual capabilities](http://opensource.com/business/15/3/docker-security-tuning) using `--cap-add` and `--cap-drop`.

CoreOS provide a [`toolbox`](https://github.com/coreos/toolbox) script (distinct from the new [docker-toolbox](https://www.docker.com/docker-toolbox)) to launch this style of container for you using `systemd-nspawn` instead of `docker` - they both run containers.

`systemd-nspawn` has different syntax to Docker, but the effect is still the same - the host system is shared with the container ([source](https://github.com/coreos/toolbox/blob/d0c1cbad37dfd455b81b1ad5c1720f07e5183811/toolbox#L31-L38)):

```
sudo systemd-nspawn \
  --directory="${machinepath}" \
  --capability=all \
  --share-system \
  --bind=/:/media/root \
  --bind=/usr:/media/root/usr \
  --bind=/run:/media/root/run \
  --user="${TOOLBOX_USER}" "$@"
```

In summary, you can launch a container and install debugging tools that can inspect the host (and by extension, other containers) by using Docker with specific volume mounts and/or `--privileged`, or CoreOS's [toolbox](https://github.com/coreos/toolbox).

---

n.b. my personal preference for debugging containers is [Sysdig](http://www.sysdig.org/install/): "Think about sysdig as strace + tcpdump + htop + iftop + lsof + ...awesome sauce." - which currently looks like:

```
docker run -i -t --name sysdig --privileged \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/host/var/run/docker.sock -v /dev:/host/dev \
  -v /proc:/host/proc:ro -v /boot:/host/boot:ro \
  -v /lib/modules:/host/lib/modules:ro -v /usr:/host/usr:ro sysdig/sysdig
```

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [cadvisor](http://blog.tutum.co/2014/08/07/using-cadvisor-to-monitor-docker-containers/), a tool from google.

cadvisor mounts `/sys` and `/var/run/` and is therefore able to monitor the host.

Comment: One of the best solution I've seen so far to monitor both host and other Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker container should not be aware of the host, so this is against the Docker/process isolation philosophy. You may find some tricks in order to do so, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Understood and normally I fully agree with this.  In this case, I'm looking for the exception to the rule as there are cases where some more detailed tools would be great (top/ps don't cut it all the time).  This is only something that admins/developers would be using, so in this case the risk of misuse is low.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I've found that you can do is capture file system events that happen in the host using inotify. I use that in my inotify-command container. But who knows if that will last...